# Почему не получается создать явную специализацию шаблона функции?

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
T Max(T a, T b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
struct box {
    double height;
    double width;
    double length;
    double volume;
};
void setVolume(box &b) {
    b.volume = b.height * b.width * b.length;
}
template <> double Max<box>(box b1, box b2) { //Ошибка
    return b1.volume > b2.volume ? b1.volume : b2.volume;
}
int main() {
    box b1 = { 5, 4, 2 };
    box b2 = { 10, 10, 2 };
    setVolume(b1);
    setVolume(b2);
    cout << Max(b1, b2) << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Ошибка    C2912   явная специализация; "double Max(box,box)" не является специализацией функции**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В шаблоне ясно сказано: принимает два `T`, возвращает `T`. У вас - принимает два `box`, но возвращает-то не `box`, а `double`...

Это - **не** специализация *вашего* шаблона.

Вы можете сделать [так](https://ideone.com/eZ6PWS):

```
template<>
box Max<box>(box b1, box b2) {
    return b1.volume > b2.volume ? b1 : b2;
}
```

Или [так](https://ideone.com/XL67OR):

```
template <class T>
auto Max(T a, T b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
};

template<>
auto Max<box>(box b1, box b2) { 
    return b1.volume > b2.volume ? b1.volume : b2.volume;
}
```